# What is the Symbol function in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I tried checking MDN for resources on this, but the only one I came across was [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Symbols), and that doesn't mention any such functions existing.

I don't see this `Symbol` function in Chromium, but I do see it in Chrome (unstable, v35). Is this just some experimental tech, considering it isn't there in Firefox or Chromium?

[image: Screenshot from console]

Comment: http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/symbols/

Comment: @thefourtheye Oh, well, that was simple. Thanks! You could post that as an answer

Comment: That doesn't qualify as an answer. Lets wait for somebody to explain it properly :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a mechanism for defining "private" members on objects.  This is useful for properly encapsulating an ECMAScript object without using closures, WeakMaps, or other techniques to hide private data for an object.

The current specification can be found here:
[ES6 Draft - Symbol](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-symbol-objects)

Here are some usage examples along with other techniques:
[Private properties in JavaScript](https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript)

And here is an example:

```
var Person = (function () {
    var name_ = new Symbol();
    function Person(name) {
        this[name_] = name;
    }
    Person.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
        name: { get: function () { return this[name_]; } }
    }
})();
```

In the above example, the `name_` symbol is not accessible outside the closure, and does not add any keys to the object that can be reflected upon by any ES5 methods.  The `name_` symbol must be accessible to outside code to access the values associated with it on instances constructed from the `Person` constructor.